# How to force redirect traffic to local proxies in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, proxy

(sorry for bad English).
On Windows 10, I need to force redirect traffic to a local proxy (in the system itself) so that the proxy settings in the programs themselves are ignored (for example, firefox has its own proxy settings that ignore netsh presets).
So that you roughly understand what I want to say how it works for me on Linux.
The firewall is configured to redirect from the guest user on all ports (the main ones get access directly) to the local proxy with the whitelist. Redirection is forced and traffic, regardless of the guest's settings, goes to the proxy, so even if the proxy settings are changed in the browser, it will either continue to forcibly work with the local proxy, or will not be able to connect to the Internet.
Can this be somehow implemented on Windows using built-in components or free software?

Comment: Have you checked out [`route`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008) || [`New-NetRoute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netroute?view=win10-ps)?

Comment: I will look at the functions of the route. thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like that can force the proxy, you need a router with a function of redirect or proxy setting.

So whenever the setting is in software is still using the proxy of the router.

Correct me if I'm wrong about this one.

Comment: Yes. And this solution is present on the part of the provider in our institution. But the problem is that some users may simply come with their own modem. I cannot physically restrict access. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: your point is to make windows disabling the internet?

Comment: Practically. In addition to access to the proxy, it provides access to the Internet. To a specific proxy. The rest should also be blocked.

Comment: You can check to Run - gpedit.msc - computer configuration - network - network connection.
  Or in user configuration same hierarchy.

and you can set in firewall and making firewall disappear but working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Windows itself does not offer such functionality, you may consider using tools like [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/) instead.